# Typo3 - Enable microdata attributes itemprop, itemscope and itemtype in RTE

Tags: html, typo3, rich-text-editor, microdata, rte

To enable [microdata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_%28HTML%29) in RTE i think i have to add the attributes for each tag in RTE config in the root pages TSconfig.

There are many examples, how to add a attribute for a tag, e.g. xml:lang:

```
RTE.default.proc {
  entryHTMLparser_db = 1
  entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
  entryHTMLparser_db.tags.div.allowedAttribs = xml:lang
}
```

This works very fine.

But when i try to adopt this for itemprop, itemscope and itemtype:

```
RTE.default.proc {
  entryHTMLparser_db = 1
  entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
  entryHTMLparser_db.tags.div.allowedAttribs = itemprop, itemscope, itemtype
}
```

it's not working.
Does somebody know how to add microdata attributes in RTE?

Comment: Did you check the manual? I think I saw it there (and I am too lazy to copy&paste it now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pgampe Did you mean the TYPO3 4.7 Specifications? http://wiki.typo3.org/TYPO3_4.7#HTML5_frontend_rendering

The site, where i want to enable microdata attributes, is a Typo3 4.5 LTS. So i think there is no possibility to use microdata in Typo3 < 4.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enter this into the `tsconfig`? It seems to work fine for me. You will need to specify the attributes `itemscope="itemscope"` on the `div` tag.